# Recursive function in R with ending point varying by group

Tags: r, function, recursion

I wish to use a recursive structure in my dplyr change that iterates on the number of lags used on certain operations. The thing is that I am not sure how to set its ending point since it resembles more a `while` than a `for` loop, which makes me a bit insecure.

Here is some sample data. Groups are not necessarily the same size and are indexed by `id`

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
                        2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5), 
                  p201 = c(NA, NA, "001", NA, NA, NA, "001", "001", "001", NA, NA), 
                 V2009 = c(25, 11, 63, 75, 49, 14, 32, 31, 3, 10, 3),
                 ager = c(2.3, 2, 8.1, 12.1, 5.1, 2, 2.9, 2.8, 2,
                          2, 2), 
                 V2007 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
)
```

I wish to update `p201` according to how similar to its lags is an observation in a given group.

This is how I would do in a first iteration:

```
new <- df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
mutate(
    p201 = ifelse(!is.na(p201), p201,
                      ifelse(
                        V2007 == lag(V2007, 1) & 
                        abs(V2009 - lag(V2009, 1)) <= ager,
                        first(na.omit(p201)), p201)))
```

My question is how could I write a recursive function that fits in a `dplyr` chain that iterates on `i` in `lag(VAR, i)` - I want `i` to grow until either thing happens: there are no more `NA`s in `p201` and all possible lags are tried in each group. Regarding the latter, it should be said that the number of rows in each group varies.

I thought about two possibilities: making the maximum value of `i` be the number of rows of the largest group - 1 or it being the number of rows of each group - 1. I'm not sure what solution is the optimal one, nor do I know how to implement this.

Could somebody help?

Here is the desired output:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 5
# Groups:   id [5]
      id p201  V2009  ager V2007
   <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    1 NA       25  2.3      1
 2    1 NA       11  2        1
 3    1 001      63  8.1      1
 4    1 001      75 12.2      1
 5    2 NA       49  5.1      2
 6    2 NA       14  2        2
 7    3 001      32  2.9      1
 8    4 001      31  2.8      2
 9    5 001       3  2        1
10    5 NA       10  2        1
11    5 001       3  2        1
```

Comment: Can you give the desired output for this sample data so we can test and verify possible solutions?

Comment: @MrFlick please check the edited question

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito Are there ever >1 `p201 == 001` in an `id` group?

Comment: @CPak I think it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you are describing is really recursive, in that the calculations don't depend on the results of previous iterations. It is, however, fairly complex, and perhaps the best way to fit it into a `dplyr` pipeline is to declare a function that takes the necessary variables and returns your answer.

Here is a function that does the trick. It uses the split-lapply-merge paradigm to force the calculations to work properly row-wise. It then uses an sapply to check whether, for each row, the logical conditions are met in any previous row in the group. If so, it overwrites an `NA` in that rows `p201` value with a non-NA value:

```r
multi_condition <- function(id, v1, v2, v3, v4)
{
  unlist(lapply(split(data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4), id), function(x) 
  {
    if(all(is.na(x$v1))) return(x$v1)
    
    ss <- unlist(c(FALSE, sapply(seq_along(x$v2)[-1], function(i) 
    {
      x$v2[i] %in% x$v2[1:(i - 1)] & any(abs(x$v3[i] - x$v3[1:(i - 1)]) <= x$v4[i])
    })))   
    replace(x$v1, ss, x$v1[!is.na(x$v1)][1])    
  }))
}
```

So the function itself is complex, but its use is straightforward:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(p201 = multi_condition(id, p201, V2007, V2009, ager))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [5]
#>       id p201  V2009  ager V2007
#>    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1 <NA>     25   2.3     1
#>  2     1 <NA>     11   2       1
#>  3     1 001      63   8.1     1
#>  4     1 001      75  12.1     1
#>  5     2 <NA>     49   5.1     2
#>  6     2 <NA>     14   2       2
#>  7     3 001      32   2.9     1
#>  8     4 001      31   2.8     2
#>  9     5 001       3   2       1
#> 10     5 <NA>     10   2       1
#> 11     5 001       3   2       1
```

If you prefer a more `dplyr` - type solution using `group_map`, with the logic perhaps a little clearer, you could try:

```r
multi_select <- function(df, ...) 
{
  rowwise_logic <- function(i) 
  {
    if(i == 1) return(FALSE)
    j <- 1:(i - 1)
    df$V2007[i] %in% df$V2007[j] & 
    any(abs(df$V2009[i] - df$V2009[j]) <= df$ager[i])
  }
  
  matching_rows <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), rowwise_logic)  
  df$p201[matching_rows] <- first(na.exclude(df$p201))

  return(df)
}
```

Which would work like this:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_map(multi_select, .keep = TRUE) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you! This is really helpful, though a bit confusing for me. I will try to transform this using tidyverse stuff. Do you think this framework can be applied using something like ```group_map``` and ```group_modify```. Besides that, I didn't understand the part where you write ```unlist(c(FALSE, ...```. Could you clarify on that?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito yes, the split-apply-bind logic can be done via passing a somewhat simpler function to `group_map`. I have added this to the answer and hopefully it makes the logic a bit clearer.

Comment: thank you! If I wanted to include an extra condition (iterating on the lag), like ```lag(V1, 1) != 1```, in ```rowwise_logic```, I should have ```any(df$V1[j] != 1)```, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish what you want with 2 `group_bys`, first on `(id, V2007)` and then after creating a dummy variable, `counter`, on `(id, V2007, counter)`. The idea behind `counter` is to sub-divide records in `id, V2007` when `p201 == 001`. See the dummy example below

```
id | p201 | V2007 | counter
 1 |   NA |     1 |       0
 1 |  001 |     1 |       1     <= (+1 to counter)
 1 |   NA |     1 |       1
 1 |  001 |     1 |       2     <= (+1 to counter)
```

After the second `group_by` this is subdivided into

```
id | p201 | V2007 | counter
 1 |   NA |     1 |       0   (group 1-A OR 1)
----------------------------
 1 |  001 |     1 |       1   (group 1-B OR 2)
 1 |   NA |     1 |       1
----------------------------
 1 |  001 |     1 |       2   (group 1-C OR 3)
```

After the second `group_by`, `p201` will 'copy' a non-NA value if the row matches 3 following conditions

- `p201` IS `NA`
- IS NOT FIRST ROW OF SUB-GROUP

  - `cond1 = row_number() > 1`
- ABS(`V2009` - FIRST(`V2009`)) <= `AGER`

  - `cond2 = abs(V2009 - first(V2009)) <= ager`

See solution

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(p201 = as.character(p201)) %>%
    group_by(id, V2007) %>% 
    mutate(counter = cumsum(ifelse(is.na(p201), 0, p201))) %>%
    group_by(id, V2007, counter) %>%
    mutate(cond1 = row_number() > 1) %>%
    mutate(cond2 = abs(V2009 - first(V2009)) <= ager) %>%
    mutate(p201 = ifelse(is.na(p201) & cond1 & cond2, first(p201), p201)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-counter, -cond1, -cond2)

# A tibble: 11 x 5
      id p201  V2009  ager V2007
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 NA       25   2.3     1
 2     1 NA       11   2       1
 3     1 001      63   8.1     1
 4     1 001      75  12.1     1
 5     2 NA       49   5.1     2
 6     2 NA       14   2       2
 7     3 001      32   2.9     1
 8     4 001      31   2.8     2
 9     5 001       3   2       1
10     5 NA       10   2       1
11     5 001       3   2       1
```

A more detailed look into the solution - if I exclude the last 2 lines, you can see the new columns that were created

```
# A tibble: 11 x 8
# Groups:   id, V2007, counter [6]
      id p201  V2009  ager V2007 counter cond1 cond2
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
 1     1 NA       25   2.3     1       0 FALSE TRUE
 2     1 NA       11   2       1       0 TRUE  FALSE
 3     1 001      63   8.1     1       1 FALSE TRUE
 4     1 001      75  12.1     1       1 TRUE  TRUE
 5     2 NA       49   5.1     2       0 FALSE TRUE
 6     2 NA       14   2       2       0 TRUE  FALSE
 7     3 001      32   2.9     1       1 FALSE TRUE
 8     4 001      31   2.8     2       1 FALSE TRUE
 9     5 001       3   2       1       1 FALSE TRUE
10     5 NA       10   2       1       1 TRUE  FALSE
11     5 001       3   2       1       1 TRUE  TRUE
```

Let's first look at `counter` - created after first grouping on `id, V2007`

```
# A tibble: 11 x 8
# Groups:   id, V2007, counter [6]
      id p201  V2009  ager V2007 counter 
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> 
 ------------- GROUP 1 -----------------
 1     1 NA       25   2.3     1       0 
 2     1 NA       11   2       1       0 
 3     1 001      63   8.1     1       1   <= (+1 when p201 == '001')
 4     1 NA       75  12.1     1       1  
 ------------- GROUP 2 -----------------
 5     2 NA       49   5.1     2       0  
 6     2 NA       14   2       2       0 
 ------------- GROUP 3 -----------------
 7     3 001      32   2.9     1       1   <= (+1 when p201 == '001')
 -------------- GROUP 4 ----------------
 8     4 001      31   2.8     2       1   <= (+1 when p201 == '001')
 etc
```

Now let's look at `cond1` created after 2nd grouping on `id, V2007, counter`

```
# A tibble: 11 x 8
# Groups:   id, V2007, counter [6]
      id p201  V2009  ager V2007 counter cond1 
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl> 
 ---------------- GROUP 1 -------------------- 
 1     1 NA       25   2.3     1       0 FALSE   <= ROW_NUMBER == 1 => FALSE
 2     1 NA       11   2       1       0 TRUE    <= ROW_NUMBER > 1 => TRUE
 ---------------- GROUP 2 --------------------
 3     1 001      63   8.1     1       1 FALSE   <= ROW_NUMBER == 1 => FALSE
 4     1 NA      75  12.1     1        1 TRUE    <= ROW_NUMBER > 1 => TRUE
 ---------------- GROUP 3 -------------------- 
 5     2 NA       49   5.1     2       0 FALSE   <= ROW_NUMBER == 1 => FALSE
 6     2 NA       14   2       2       0 TRUE    <= ROW_NUMBER > 1 => TRUE
 <skip>
 ---------------- GROUP N --------------------
 9     5 001       3   2       1       1 FALSE   <= ROW_NUMBER == 1 => FALSE
10     5 NA       10   2       1       1 TRUE    <= ROW_NUMBER > 1 => TRUE
11     5 NA        3   2       1       1 TRUE    <= ROW_NUMBER > 1 => TRUE
```

Finally look at `cond2` - `abs(V2009 - first(V2009)) <= ager`

```
# A tibble: 11 x 8
# Groups:   id, V2007, counter [6]
      id p201  V2009  ager V2007 counter cond1 cond2
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
 ---------------- GROUP 1 ------------------------      first(V2009) in this group is 25
 1     1 NA       25   2.3     1       0 FALSE TRUE     <= abs(25 - 25) <= 2.3 => TRUE
 2     1 NA       11   2       1       0 TRUE  FALSE    <= abs(11 - 25) <= 2 => FALSE

 ---------------- GROUP 2 ------------------------      first(V2009) in this group is 63
 3     1 001      63   8.1     1       1 FALSE TRUE     <= abs(63 - 63) <= 8.1 => TRUE
 4     1 NA       75  12.1     1       1 TRUE  TRUE     <= abs(75 - 63) <= 12.1 => TRUE

 ---------------- GROUP 3 ------------------------      <= first(V2009) in this group is 49
 5     2 NA       49   5.1     2       0 FALSE TRUE     <= abs(49 - 49) <= 5.1 => TRUE
 6     2 NA       14   2       2       0 TRUE  FALSE    <= abs(14 - 49) <= 2 => FALSE
 <skip>

 ---------------- GROUP N ------------------------      <= first(V2009) in this group is 3
 9     5 001       3   2       1       1 FALSE TRUE     <= abs(3 - 3) <= 2 => TRUE
10     5 NA       10   2       1       1 TRUE  FALSE    <= abs(10 - 3) <= 2 => FALSE
11     5 NA        3   2       1       1 TRUE  TRUE     <= abs(3 - 3) <= 2 => TRUE
```

Finally, `ifelse(is.na(p201) & cond1 & cond2, first(p201), p201)`. This statement translates to, 'IF p201 IS NA AND COND1 == TRUE AND COND2 == TRUE, THEN ASSIGN P201 = FIRST(P201), ELSE P201 DOES NOT CHANGE'

```
# A tibble: 11 x 8
# Groups:   id, V2007, counter [6]
      id p201  V2009  ager V2007 counter cond1 cond2
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl> <lgl>
---------------- GROUP 1 ------------------------
 1     1 NA       25   2.3     1       0 FALSE TRUE     <= P201 DOES NOT CHANGE BECAUSE COND1 IS FALSE
 2     1 NA       11   2       1       0 TRUE  FALSE    <= P201 DOES NOT CHANGE BECAUSE COND2 IS FALSE

---------------- GROUP 2 ------------------------       <= FIRST(P201) == '001' FOR THIS GROUP
 3     1 001      63   8.1     1       1 FALSE TRUE     <= P201 DOES NOT CHANGE BECAUSE P201 == '001' AND COND1 IS FALSE
 4     1 001      75  12.1     1       1 TRUE  TRUE     <= P201 = FIRST(P201) BECAUSE ALL 3 CONDITIONS ARE TRUE (P201 WAS ORIGINALLY NA HERE)

---------------- GROUP 3 ------------------------
 5     2 NA       49   5.1     2       0 FALSE TRUE    <= P201 DOES NOT CHANGE BECAUSE COND1 IS FALSE
 6     2 NA       14   2       2       0 TRUE  FALSE   <= P201 DOES NOT CHANGE BECAUSE COND2 IS FALSE
 <skip>

---------------- GROUP N ------------------------
 9     5 001       3   2       1       1 FALSE TRUE    <= P201 DOES NOT CHANGE BECAUSE COND1 IS FALSE
10     5 NA       10   2       1       1 TRUE  FALSE   <= P201 DOES NOT CHANGE BECAUSE COND2 IS FALSE
11     5 001       3   2       1       1 TRUE  TRUE    <= P201 = FIRST(P201) BECAUSE ALL 3 CONDITIONS ARE TRUE (P201 WAS ORIGINALLY NA HERE)
```

Hopefully that helps.

I added

```
mutate(p201 = as.character(p201))
```

because it converts `p201` into an integer otherwise.

Comment: thank you! Does this generalizes easily when there are multiple conditions? I mean, there are multiple conditions either of the form of ```V2007 == lag(V2007, 1)``` with other variables,  or ```abs(V2009 - lag(V2009, 1)) <= ager``` or ```lag(V2005, 1) == 4``` and so forth. Do I need more of group_by or to group by more variables?

Comment: It depends, is the short answer. StackOverflow is best for tackling a small test-case, where hopefully the answer helps you to understand different ways of tackling that case. Your 1,000 test-cases may require the same approach or not. If you have more test-cases and more questions and aren't sure whether any answers here will generalize, make another post. Or edit your post with additional test-cases (and expected outcomes).

Comment: but is there a specific reason for first grouping on V2007? I mean, if there are other tests just like the one with V2007 but with some other variable x, should I just do ```group_by(id, V2007, x)```?

Comment: I grouped on `V2007` to match your following condition `V2007 == lag(V2007, 1)`. If you don't need `V2007` to match lagged values, then you don't need to group on `V2007` in the first grouping.

Comment: Sorry for insisting - I just don't have my dataset to test it right now. But where in the code do I ensure myself that only after not finding a match with one lag, I jump to the next and so forth? A related point is, how would this change if instead of using lags, I used leads?

Comment: First question: I'll edit my post.
Second question: if you need leads, please update your post with a test-dataset and expected outcome. Or make another post. As I said before.

Comment: thank you. Maybe in the future I will need leads. If that is the case, I might edit the question

Comment: You shouldn't say that in that tone! I'm still not allowed to do it since It was created recently - still need to wait for 16 hours

Comment: Shame on me :) :) Whether you reward or not is up to you - I can only decide to help or not.